# Scroll Bar Inside Popup Window

Tags: html, css

How do I add a Scroll Bar inside the popup window so that I can access the search results inside the PopUp window?

My code for popup window:

```
<html>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://secure.duoservers.com/tld-search/api-search.css?color=0000ff&width=700"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure.duoservers.com/tld-search/api-search.js?lang=en&store=7xhosting"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
searchApiOptions = {
    store: "7xhosting",
    containerId: "divID",
    submitURL: "",
    selectedTld: "com",
    popupBox: true,
    floatingBox: false
};
</script>
<div id="divID"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Image1] [image: Image2]

Answer (score 2):

To force the scrollbar, set [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)  to `scroll` on the element which you want to receive it, like this.

```
#divID {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have some min-height and height set in css for

```
 div#divId 
{
  min-height:300px;
  height:300px;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

and then set overflow:scroll

Answer (score 0):

```css
.divID{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:auto;
  min-height:200px;
  max-height:250px;
}
```

instead of `id` give `class` to your div.
I have given `overflow-y:auto` so the scrollbar only visible if there is an overflow in div.

Hope this helps.